# Submission issue internal server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, regex

I am trying to submit data through form as below which gives error:

```
echo 'The # here does not begin a comment.'
echo The \# here does not begin a comment.
```

But it wont give error, if we submit like below:

```
echo The # here does not begin a comment.
echo The # here does not begin a comment.
```

That is ,without single quotes and slash ,i am unable to submit data.

Code as below:

```
 function AjaxCallOnClick(userName, email, commentText, blogID, commentHtml, onCommentEmailID) {

        var parameters = "{'commentUserName':'" + userName + "','email':'" + email + "','commentText':'" + commentText + "','blogID':'" + blogID + "','commentHtml':'" + commentHtml + "','onCommentEmailID':'" + onCommentEmailID + "'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/BlogService.asmx/GetShareStoryData")%>",
            data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
            alert("Your Comment was Saved");
                var getCommentList = response.d;
                var allComments = '';
                $('#dvMainAndReplyCommentSection').html('');
                $.each(getCommentList, function (index, comments) {
                    var comment = comments.HtmlComment;
                    allComments += comment;
                });
                if (allComments) {
                    $('#dvMainAndReplyCommentSection').html(allComments);
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

What is the work around for this?

Comment: no need to `"  "` for defining object `parameters `.

Comment: But currently users put this type of text in field and what about forward slash? it is also not accepting.

Comment: did you try code in below.

Comment: I think,also you have to use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this format var parameters = JSON.stringify({ commentUserName: userName, email: email, commentText: commentText, blogID: blogID, commentHtml: commentHtml, onCommentEmailID: onCommentEmailID }); and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it...Removes double quotes when saving object.

```
function AjaxCallOnClick(userName, email, commentText, blogID, commentHtml, onCommentEmailID) {

var parameters = JSON.stringify({'commentUserName': userName,'email': email,'commentText': commentText,'blogID': blogID,'commentHtml': commentHtml,'onCommentEmailID': onCommentEmailID});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/BlogService.asmx/GetShareStoryData")%>",
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        alert("Your Comment was Saved");
           var res=JSON.parse(response);
            var getCommentList = res.d;
            var allComments = '';
            $('#dvMainAndReplyCommentSection').html('');
            $.each(getCommentList, function (index, comments) {
                var comment = comments.HtmlComment;
                allComments += comment;
            });
            if (allComments) {
                $('#dvMainAndReplyCommentSection').html(allComments);
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            var res=JSON.parse(response);
            alert(res.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I tried below code but in simple text only it is throwing internal server error.

Comment: It is not going in success section only then what is the need of using JSON.parse function. but my previous parameter structure simple text is working.

Comment: if your `response` is in json format then need to use of `JSON.parse()`.Try to check with both.

Comment: i dont understand your `url`.what is this.

Comment: This url is used as webservice where method is GetShareStoryData for transaction from database.

Comment: i tried like this and it works. var parameters = JSON.stringify({ commentUserName: userName, email: email, commentText: commentText, blogID: blogID, commentHtml: commentHtml, onCommentEmailID: onCommentEmailID });